# Fastest Azure Blob Storage Replication method?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have a situation where we now need to replicate all data from our Blob Storage account to another node in the same rough region (think WE Europe to NE Europe).

Currently we have only 1 application that writes content to certain containers, and other applications that write to other containers.

I'd ideally like to replicate all of them.

I've looked into the following:

1. Azure Blob Storage Geo-replication.
2. Azure Event Grid
3. Just writing the blobs in other applications themselves.

The issue with 1. is that the delivery time of the updated blob is not guaranteed. This could take upto 5 minutes, for example, which is too long in our use case. This is defined in their SLA.

The issue with 2. is that there is no guarantee of delivery time - only that delivery will take place at least once, whether it's to the intended destination, or a deadletter queue.

The issue with 3. is latency, cost & having to reengineer a few applications at once.

Expanding on 3. - we have an application that listens to messages published to Azure Service Bus. It acts upon those messages and creates blobs based off data that is stored in a DB on-site. It then uploads the blobs to the specific container it pertains to, and publshes a message saying it has done so.
The problem here is that we'd need to write from one data center, to another, incurring bandwidth charges, and ask this application to do double the work.
We would also need to ensure that blobs are written, and implement a method to ensure consistency - i.e. if one location goes down, we need to be able to replicate once it's back up.

So - what's the fastest replication method here? I'm assuming it's number 3. However, could there be another solution that has not been thought of so far?

Edit: 4. Have the generated files sent to Service Bus as messages and be picked up by applications dedicated to write, hosted in each geo-location.
Issue here is limitations on message size (makes sense!) we have files over 1MB.

Comment: can you please try [azure function blob trigger](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob.md#input---c-script-example)? There is no size limitation.

Comment: I will take a look into it, thanks! It's one thing i've not looked into before.

Comment: Unfortunatley, it suffers the same problems as Event Grid stuff - as it's essentially the same thing.